# Iphone Access rootviewcontroller from subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a navigation based application, from any of my subUIviewcontrollers when they click a button on the toolbar, I want to send rootviewcontroller the checked rowId or entered text. So I want to manage everything from Rootviewcontroller(e.g which page to show next)

But this code below does not hit the answeredValues in my rootcontroller, even gives a warning that it might not respond. why is that? and if there is a better way to this things like from delegete class?

in interface

```
-(void)answerValues:(NSMutableArray*)values;
```

in implementation

```
-(void) answerValues:(NSMutableArray*)values  {

    //get answer value
    //edit insert xml with new answer
    //make connection
    //Get XML
    //Parse and get the last page of questions
    //Return a variable object filled with question and answers 
}

RootViewController *root = (RootViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] ; 

[root answerValues:values];
```

Comment: Can you post `RootViewController` interface/implementation?

Comment: Are you sure you did not mispell the name of the method? In the original question, you called `answeredValues`, but now I see your method is named `answerValues`.

Comment: @albertamg  ah ok..mistypo..thank you I did it..anyway is this a good place for managing things or I should use delegate?

Comment: You are welcome! I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, you mispelled the name of the method. In the original question, you called a method named `answeredValues`, but in your updated question your method is named `answerValues`.